# How to make homescreen have more tiles

Tags: 8.1, settings, tiles, live-tiles

I have seen in videos of Windows Phone 8.1 that some homescreens have 3 medium tiles in one row or 6 small tiles. My screen only has 2 medium tiles to a row or 4 small tiles and as I have a lot of applications I'm just wondering how this is accomplished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very simple, just go to **Settings** → **Start + theme** and enable the "Show more tiles" option. This enables two extra small tiles or one extra medium tile per row.

For more information, see these links:

- [Personalising your Start screen and theme colour - WindowsPhone.com](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/personalize-my-start-screen-and-theme-color)
- [Windows Phone 8.1 Tip: Show More Tiles - WinSupersite.com](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-81-tip-show-more-tiles)